# RoR send email and OpenSSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I have some class **settings_mailer.rb** for sending email, code:

```
require 'tlsmail'

Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address =>  "mail.dcs.com",
    :port =>  "587",
    :domain => 'localhost.localdomain',
    :enable_starttls_auto =>  true,
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name => "support@dcs.com",
    :password => "dcs00001",
    :enable_starttls_auto => false
}

class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from =>  "support@dcs.com"

  def notification(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to =>  user.email, :subject =>  "Welcome to My Awesome Site")
  end
end
```

And I have some controller **settings_controller.rb** in which present method **get_user_settings** and in witch I call my **notification** method for send test email.
Code:

```
def get_user_settings
    Mailer.notification('theemail@gmail.com').deliver
 end
```

But if I run my app and call this method I catch next error:

```
[2015-06-21 09:34:35] [/home/tk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb] [FATAL] 
NameError (uninitialized constant Appdev::SettingsController::Mailer):
  app/controllers/appdev/settings_controller.rb:251:in `get_user_settings'
```

Why is happens, and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My working code:
**mailer.rb**

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address =>  "mail.dcs.com",
    :port =>  "587",
    :domain => 'localhost.localdomain',
    :enable_starttls_auto =>  true,
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name => "support@dcs.com",
    :password => "dcs00001",
    :enable_starttls_auto => false
}

class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from =>  "support@dcs.com"

  def notification(user)
    mail(:to =>  user, :subject =>  "Welcome to My Awesome Site")
  end
end
```

**2. ../view/mailer/notification.html.rb**
It is some email html template

And call my email method for send message:

```
Mailer.notification('theemail@gmail.com').deliver
```

Answer (score 0):

> NameError (uninitialized constant Appdev::SettingsController::Mailer)

The error is because your ***file name*** is **`settings_mailer.rb`** whereas your **`Class`** name is **`Mailer`**. You need to change it to **`SettingsMailer`**

```
class SettingsMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from =>  "support@dcs.com"

  def notification(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to =>  user.email, :subject =>  "Welcome to My Awesome Site")
  end
end
```

And also you need to change in `get_user_settings` method also

```
def get_user_settings
   SettingsMailer.notification('bad.kto@gmail.com').deliver
end
```

Comment: no. not working. NameError (uninitialized constant Appdev::SettingsController::SettingsMailer):
  app/controllers/appdev/settings_controller.rb:251:in `get_user_settings'

Comment: @Taras Kovalenko what happens when you change the file name to `setting_mailer.rb` and class name to `SettingMailer`. Notice removed `s`?

Comment: nothing - NameError (Appdev::SettingsController::SettingMailer):

Comment: @TarasKovalenko Did you changed it in `get_user_settings` method too?